# malloc inside a loop

Tags: c++, proc

How safe  is it, specially the performance, to allocate memory dynamically inside a loop, if the number of blocks are not known in advance.

I have a Pro*c file , which has a cursor. I need to get the data from DB and allocate to C structure. I am not sure if there is any way to find number of records in a cursor.

Comment: Are you looking for C or C++?

Comment: my application is a mix of C and C++ code, so doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

If it's what you need, then go for it. There is nothing about loop syntax in C++ that affects `malloc`; they just have nothing to do with each other.

But `malloc` is usually not the right choice in C++. Slightly better would be using the type-safe `new` / `delete` operators, and best is usually a container such as `std::vector<>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My application uses lot of c struct, so I have to use malloc. How can I use vector with struct??

Comment: You're using C or C++? In C++, you use it exactly the same as a class. `std::vector<MyStruct> many_structs;`...

Comment: @omsarathe There is no problem to use `std::vector` with C structure if it is safe-copyable (doesn't contain pointers to dynamically allocated and owned objects or pointers to itself). But if not you will experience problems even with `malloc/free` approach. Actually `std::vector` is designed to be compatible with C arrays. Just define `std::vector<StructName>` object and don't forget to include `<vector>` header.

Comment: Or maybe std::vector<*MyStruct> - no copy required and so safe/efficient for structs/objects of any complexity/size,  (not tried with C/C++ interop).